# Best Method for AS3 Data Services Update after Underlying Database Schema Changed?

Tags: actionscript-3, data-binding, flash-builder

I am using Flash Builder 4 to write Flex app. I originally used its php data service wizard to create the php class and related valueObject that interface with my database.

Now when I change my underlying database schema, what is the best way to update that php class and valueObject? I currently have to delete and recreate them using the wizard again. But this is not a good way as I may write customized routines in the php class in the future for more specific queries.

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks!